# category based queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, categories

I want to write a query in mysql. my scenario is as follow:

```
Class   Minmarks  MaxMarks
A         751      1000
B         501      750
c         251      500
D         1        250
```

there are 3 columns: class,minmarks ,maxmarks. If I got 450 marks then what is my class? How to write this in mysql?

Answer (score 2):

Hey you can write query this way. You can replace your marks with `given_marks` here with `450`

```
select class from table_name where given_marks >= Minmarks and given_marks <= Maxmarks
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT Class FROM table_name WHERE Minmarks >= 450 and MaxMarks <= 450`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11197211)

Comment: @LucaDetomi Which part of my statement was a critique or comment asking for clarification?

Comment: You answer was flagged as too short ad so more suitable as comment than as answer. Please, add details to let users understand "why" your answer is a good one or maybe the best one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Greater than Equals & Less Than Equals Clause or Alternatively you can use Between..And Clause

```
SELECT class FROM <table_name> WHERE marks BETWEEN usc_code AND a.usc_value;
```